# No Audio on Quicktime Screen Cap Video

Tags: quicktime

I'm using Quicktime 10.3 on a mac running 10.9.5. I've done several screen capture videos and recorded my voice using a Logitech USB headset/microphone. I've not updated anything. It worked yesterday and not today. But all of a sudden - no audio. I've run through the basics but still can't figure it out. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure output volume for your microphone is high enough in System Preferences > Audio and that you have the right microphone input selected in Quick Time?

Comment: Which basics did you try? Does it work with the builtin mic? Does the headset work with FaceTime or Skype?